# How can I change the character spacing in pptx-python?

Tags: python, powerpoint, spacing, python-pptx, kerning

What I try to do is change the spacing for each run in the function:

```
def add_direction_arrows(self):
    global junc_file, junc_file_name
    match_colors_to_type = {"White": RGBColor(255, 255, 255), "Yellow": RGBColor(238, 233, 23)}
    arrows_placeholders = {"NORTH_ARROWS": self.NO.LAN.Organize_arrows_order(),
                           "SOUTH_ARROWS": self.SO.LAN.Organize_arrows_order(),
                           "EAST_ARROWS": self.EA.LAN.Organize_arrows_order(),
                           "WEST_ARROWS": self.WE.LAN.Organize_arrows_order()}
    for slide in junc_file.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.name in arrows_placeholders.keys():
                text_frame = shape.text_frame
                text_frame.clear()
                arrows_list = arrows_placeholders[shape.name]
                for arrow in arrows_list:
                    text_frame = shape.text_frame
                    p = text_frame.paragraphs[0]
                    run = p.add_run()
                    run.text = arrow[0] * arrow[1]
                    font = run.font
                    font.bold = False
                  ➜ font.spacing = -10
                    font.size = Pt(49.9)
                    font.color.rgb = match_colors_to_type[arrow[2]]
    junc_file.save(junc_file_name)
```

I'm not sure if the python-pptx library includes this option, but if it doesn't, what other options do I have? is it possible to add it myself? maybe a way to manually 'press a button' in powerpoint?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs `python-pptx` does not support spacing.

You could take a deep dive into how the library is working internally, and probably add support yourself, but I doubt this is really an option for you.

You can of course edit the powerpoint files by hand later to change this (or even using VBA).

Comment: Actually, out of interest I had a look at the source code. It is actually quite doable to add this option to Font by just adding a few lines of code.

Comment: Really? any suggestions on how I should start or where to look? I don't have a lot of experience with it... thanks!

Comment: Well, in the [github repository](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx) there is the definition of the `Font` class (in `text/text.py`). As you can see it is rather readable. There is a propery defined by ```def size(self):```. You can just basically copy the same code for a `spacing` property. It just needs to set and get `self._rPr.spc` instead of `sz`.
Haven't tested it but I bet that would just work.


[this](http://officeopenxml.com/drwSp-text-runProps.php)  was quite helpful to understand what is going on. It's just writing some XML, nothing fancy.

Comment: Ok, so I did as you suggested; I added this to text/text.py
  `@property
   def spacing(self):
       sz = self._rPr.spc
       if sz is None:
           return None
       return Centipoints(sz)

   @spacing.setter
   def spacing(self, emu):
       if emu is None:
           self._rPr.spc = None
       else:
           sz = Emu(emu).centipoints
           self._rPr.spc = sz` 
I get this error:  `AttributeError: 'CT_TextCharacterProperties' object has no attribute 'spc'`
I couldn't find an explanation about it, but it feels it's almost the solution... any ideas? thanks again!

Comment: Probably just you just have to add it here https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/b31cf20fe31ff0f3fe0c919111f3562bb58f8b1e/pptx/oxml/text.py

https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/develop/dev/analysis/schema/ct_textcharacterproperties.html says it is in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no support for such. As a workaround, I used the following snippet to achieve the same in shape.table context. Maybe you can look into if it behaves the same for text runs by replacing the first two lines to get the text frame txBody.

```
def _set_char_spacing(cell):
    tc = cell._tc
    txBody = tc.get_or_add_txBody()
    if not len(txBody.p_lst) > 0:
      return cell

    p = txBody.p_lst[0] # NOTE: Using index 0 just for demo purposes
    r = p.r_lst[0] # NOTE: Using index 0 just for demo purposes
    if not r.rPr:
      rPr = r._add_rPr()

    spacing = Emu(40)
    rPr.attrib['spc'] = str(spacing)
    return cell
```

As a disclaimer, p_lst and r_lst are lists that would require iterating.